# How to import XML files in WEKA

Tags: xml, weka

I want to import a bunch of xml data in weka. Is there a straightforward solution or a tutorial or I have to maually convert it to a csv or arff file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to load instances into Weka from XML. Your only real options are CSV, arff or a database, so you'll have to write some conversion code. I've used [rarff](http://github.com/wwood/rarff) in the past to build arff files using Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

WEKA does not support XML file as *input dataset*. WEKA allows to start Classifiers and Experiments with the -xml ***option*** followed by a filename to retrieve the command line options from the XML file instead of the command line. see this link:
https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/xml/index_old.html