# WEKA file formats

Tags: xml, weka, file-format, arff

Can I feed WEKA with `xml` files? Or should I use `arff` format?

thanks

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814104/how-to-import-xml-files-in-weka/3490229#3490229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading arff formatted datasets into weka has always been easiest for me (converting datasets to arff is usually not too difficult). To my knowledge, you can also load datasets from a DB or datasets that are in CSV format into Weka.  As for XML: I've never loaded an XML doc into Weka however this has promise http://weka.wikispaces.com/XRFF and might be what you need.